# How to select data from table that not inserted on other table in codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I've two tables products, stock I want to select all rows from table products that not inserted on stock and i've 2 conditions

1: column products.s_compnay_id = users.u_company_id

2: cloumn stock.s_company_id =users.u_company_id

that's my model

```
<?php
Class UserProducts_m extends CI_Model{
function index(){
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
         $name = $session_data['username'];
         $this->db->select('u_company_id');
         $this->db->from('users');
         $this->db->where('u_username', $name);
         $user_data = $query = $this->db->get();
         if ($user_data->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($query->result_array() as $row_userdata) {

                    $usercompanyid[] = $row_userdata;
                }
                $usercompany=$usercompanyid[0]['u_company_id'];
            }
            $query="select products.* from products where !FIND_IN_SET(products.p_id,select stock.s_p_id from stock and stock.s_company_id=$usercompany and p_company_id=$usercompany)";
            $this->db->query($query);
            $result= $this->db->get();
            if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($result->result_array() as $row_result) {

                    $product_data[] = $row_result;
                }
            }
            //return $result=$query->result();
}

}
?>
```

And that's my controller

```
    <?php
Class UserProducts extends CI_Controller {

    function index(){
        $this->load->model("UserProducts_m");
        $this->load->model("user");
        $this->load->view("userproducts_v",array(
                'userdata'=>$this->user->userdata(),
                'userproducts'=>$this->UserProducts_m->index()
            ));

    }

}

?>
```

that's my errors

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select stock.s_p_id from stock and stock.s_company_id=1 and p_company_id=1)' at line 1

select products.* from products where !FIND_IN_SET(products.p_id,select stock.s_p_id from stock and stock.s_company_id=1 and p_company_id=1)

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/Elvan/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try putting curly braces around the vars in your query statement. Then it should resolve to array values properly.

```
$query="select products.* from products where
   !find_in_set(products.p_id,select stock.s_p_id from stock and 
   stock.s_company_id = {$usercompanyid[0]['u_company_id']} and 
   p_company_id = {$usercompanyid[0]['u_company_id']})";
```

I see a couple other problems.

The line

```
$result= $this->db->get();
```

is not needed because `$this->db->query($query);` already returned a database result object. Do this

```
$result = $this->db->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows() > 0) 
{ ...
```

Then you have this useless block of code (Pardon me for being blunt)

```
foreach ($result->result_array() as $row_result) 
{
    $product_data[] = $row_result;
}
```

This is useless because your code just copies array values from one array to another. You'll save a lot of code execution with the following which produces the same thing your foreach loop does.

```
$product_data = $result->result_array();
```

`result->array()` returns an array where each item is an array representing a table row.

You did the same thing earlier adding items to the `$usercompanyid` array. Do this.

```
if ($user_data->num_rows() > 0) 
{
    $usercompanyid = $query->result_array();
}
```

One last problem. It appears that `UserProducts_m::index()` does not return anything.

Comment: Thanks for replying , I updated my model and i just get SQL error 
`Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select s_p_id from stock where stock.s_company_id=1 and products.p_company_id=1)' at line 1

select products.* from products where !FIND_IN_SET(products.p_id,select s_p_id from stock where stock.s_company_id=1 and products.p_company_id=1)

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/Elvan/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691`

Comment: Does mariaDB support  ! as an operator? Change it to NOT and see what happens. Also, FIND_IN_SET takes two strings as arguments. Your second argument is a select statement. Will that work? I don't see how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NOT IN sql query for this.

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE product_id NOT IN (select field name form stock where clause);
```